# saving stdout into a variable in a doctest

Tags: python, doctest

I have a doctest, and I want to save what a command I run into a variable, to use it in another function

```
   >>> sh("git finish", return_output=True).split("#")[1].split(":")[0]
   (here comes an int i want to save, say 900)
```

the sh is a command line function looking like this

```
# short alias for check_output
def sh(cmd, return_output=False):
    from subprocess import call
    open('/dev/shm/fail_output', 'w').close()
    with open('/dev/shm/fail_output', 'a+') as output:
        call(cmd, stderr=output, stdout=output, shell=True)
    with open('/dev/shm/fail_output', 'r') as output:
        if return_output:
            return output.read()
        print output.read()

return locals()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the output of a command by using popen rather than call:

```
output = Popen(["mycmd", "myarg"], stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

More information on the [subprocess documentation page](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor)